# Drawing an arc correctly with Qt5 painter

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qpainter

I am trying to draw an arc at the edge of the bounding rectangle. This is important since I want it to scale with the control. However, This leads to the edges getting clipped off when using `boundingRect()` as an argument for the `drawArc()`.

```
QBrush brush(QColor("#007430"));
painter->setBrush(brush);
QPen pen;
pen.setStyle(Qt::SolidLine);
float lineWidth1 = 6.0;
pen.setWidthF(lineWidth1);
painter->setPen(pen);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter->drawArc(boundingRect(), 45*16, 270*16);
```

[image]

To make it work correctly, I must pass in a rectangle that is 1/2 of the pen width smaller on each side. **Is there a more direct way to do this in QT without manual calculating/adjusting?**

```
QRectF arcRect(0 + lineWidth1/2,
               0 + lineWidth1/2,
               boundingRect().width() - lineWidth1,
               boundingRect().height() - lineWidth1);

painter->drawArc(arcRect, 45*16, 270*16);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to bring you the real answer which unfortunately is **no, there is no automatic way to scale to bounding box of drawing operations with `QPainter` in Qt5**. You will therefore have to calculate this in your own code on a per case basis.

On the bright side, this calculation is not very hard, and by doing it yourself you are certain to maintain full control over the process.